# Flink Querying current state of existing session

Tags: apache-flink

I am working on event stream application using Flink. 
The goal is to return the first event for a session as long is still active.
The session is not active when there are no events after X minutes.
I can do it using external DB, keep the minimum timestamp for each session, update the DB accordingly and remove it when the sessions expires.
However, I wonder if I can take advantage of Flink state. I prefer not to use queryable state, since there might be a changes in a near future as advise in the docs.

Comment: It seems like you need a queryable solution (for session X, give me the first event if it's still active), yes? Or is there some other access pattern that would work?

Comment: @kkrugler, how can I query it outside of Flink? I prefer not to use Queryable  state

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Flink's queryable state, then you'll need to use some other external system (like a DB) to maintain the `<active session> -> <first event>` relationship.